# Converting Assembly Language to Python Code

Tags: python, assembly

I am trying to convert assembly language to Python.  I'm trying to follow the assembly code as literally as possible when I do this. I know this particular code will require nested conditional statements. I'm using a,b,c,d as memory locations.

Here is the assembly language:

```
    0   IN a
    1   LOAD d
    2   COMPARE a
    3   JUMPLT 6
    4   JUMPEQ 6
    5   JUMPGT 12
    6   OUT c 
    7   LOAD a
    8   ADD b
    9   STORE c
    10  DECREMENT d
    11  JUMP 20
    12  DECREMENT c
    13  LOAD a
    14  COMPARE c
    15  JUMPLT 19
    16  JUMPEQ 19
    17  INCREMENT d   
    18  CLEAR c             
    19  OUT d
    20  OUT b
    21  HALT
```

This is my literal translation of the code into Python.

```
      a = input()

      if a<=d:
        print c
        c = a+b
        d = d-1
        print b  

      else:
        c = c-1
        if c<=a:
          print d
          print b

        else:
          d=d+1
          c=0
          print d
          print b
```

I see that print d and print b are included in the if and else nested statements so if I'm not doing a literal translation of the code, maybe it should look like this?

```
      a = input()

      if a<=d:
        print c
        c = a+b
        d = d-1
        print b 

      else:
        c = c-1
        print d
        print b

        if c>a:
          d=d+1
          c=0
```

And my final questions: are either of these translations correct?  They don't evaluate the same way.  Also are there better ways to do this translation?

Any other tips or rules to keep in mind about these conversions would be welcome.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah the part I looked at looks correct to me.  However, it would be more accurate to put `print b` after the if/else block because all the execution paths merge before it.

The asm is clunky (e.g. leave out the first two conditional branches so `JUMPGT 12` either jumps or falls through), so yes there's lots of room to simply it and/or the Python.  Beginners *very* frequently write inefficient branching that jumps one way or the other, instead of just jumping or falling through.

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful--I will try it the way you described in Python and test it.  Did you look at the first translation or the second translation or both?  Thanks again!

Comment: @Cinder1: mostly just the first, and mostly just the first `if` block / the asm from lines 6 through 11.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much!